# Access Query Criteria disabled based on IIF

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I'm sorry, but it is rather tricky for me to describe this issue, but i will try my best.

I have a query with a lot of tables with a joined column. (Numbers in numbers). See fig 1.

It is used to link numbers together, and to be able to link down a "chain", these joins are used. It is the same 2 tables used every time, where CN and CNG are join similarly. This is not an issue and it works fine.

The problem is that the numbers has a terminated option (YES/NO). When I build the over, see figure 2, i want only those that are False in terminated, shown.
This works fine, for the first level. But when i put in a criteria for level 2 and up, it only shows the lines which exists (A number does not necessarily have a sub number).

So i tried something like this criteria:

```
Like IIF(IsNull([Level 2]);"*";False)
```

The point is, i want the criteria to only work, if a sub number exist. Otherwise, it will just remove the lines without a sub number.
Figure 3 shows an example where i just put in

```
Like *
```

in the criteria. I.e. it removes those in "Final2" that has the blue square (Neither Yes nor No).

How can i work around this? Any suggestions?

[image: 213]

[image: 312]

[image: 232]

Comment: Why do you have both `mysql` and `ms-access` tags? Which database are you actually using?

Comment: There's no `IIF` in MySQL, so I guess it must be Access.

Comment: @barmar A mistake, forgive me. It is access SQL.

Comment: Sadly your english makes it hard to understand what you trying to do exactly and where the problem lies. Could you perhaps add (simplified) examples of your data and the problems you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SQL that's generated by your query, and replace the WHERE clause with something like this:

```
WHERE [Final2] LIKE IIF(IsNull([Level 2]), "*", False)
```